# Codename One: BrowserComponent and WebBrowser does not work on real Android device

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to load a WebView using Codename One but it **does not work on a real Android device** (*though it **worked** in the Codename One simulator - the page was loaded*).

I've tried both BrowserComponent and WebBrowser and both didn't work. The code are:

```
public class WebViewScreenOpR implements Runnable {

private String urlString;

public WebViewScreenOpR(String urlString) {
    super();
    this.urlString = urlString;
}

private Form webViewForm;

private void prepareAsWebBrowser() {
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser(urlString);
    webViewForm = new Form("Starlent", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    webViewForm.add(webBrowser);
}

private void prepareAsBrowserComponent() {
    webViewForm = new Form("Starlent", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();
    browserComponent.setURL(urlString);
    webViewForm.add(browserComponent);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    prepareAsBrowserComponent();
    show();
}

private void show() {
    webViewForm.show();
}
```

and to display it:

```
private class GoLiveButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        WebViewScreenOpR webViewScreenOpR = new WebViewScreenOpR("http://www.apple.com");
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(webViewScreenOpR);
    }
}
```

I've also tried the "reload()" and "setEnabled(true/false)" methods but to no avail.

On testing using a real Android device, it briefly showed a progress dialog box with the text "loading...". The dialog box then disappeared and **nothing appears**. What's wrong with my code? How can I get it work in a real Android?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the problem: the doc says "On Android this component might show a native progress indicator dialog. You can disable that functionality using the call.". However, I can't find any instruction on how to disable it. What "call"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a BorderLayout center instead your boxlayout the initial size of the browser might just be 0 height

Comment: Well, the result is the same - still, nothing shows up in the real Android device. I've tried: webViewForm = new Form("Starlent", new BorderLayout()); and  webViewForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, webBrowser);. I've also tried "webBrowser.setHeight(300);" and "webViewForm.setHeight(400);"

Comment: setting the height implicitly is almost always a mistake.

Comment: Just tried your code on my android device with this:                      private void prepareAsWebBrowser() {
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser(urlString);
    webViewForm = new Form("Starlent", new BorderLayout());
    webViewForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, webBrowser);
}
and it worked fine